# Rails: Proxy Authentication in Watir (Chrome Driver)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, watir

i've tried to add proxy authentication in `chrome` webdriver which run on the watir like belows:

```
require 'watir'
proxies = ['--proxy-server=185.264.167.184:63109', '--proxy-auth=username:password']
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => proxies
browser.goto(url)
```

when the browser run it still asking me username and password like below:
[image]

And the question is how to set username and password in chrome driver which run on the `watir` ?

Comment: Try specifying Watir 6.5.0 and see if it works. I might have broken something after that release, and I need to spend some time investigating.

Comment: Try URL Authentication. Like `http://user:password@example.com`.

Comment: hi @titusfortner, using watir 6.5.0 still not works

Comment: @Gokul, your suggestion not works too

Comment: Try `browser.switchTo()` to get the handle of the popup/alert box

Comment: duh man the pop is not generated by html @Gokul

Comment: Anyone figured this out ??

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible atm with raw Chrome, but it works using a Chrome-extension.

There's allready a [python-script](https://github.com/Smartproxy/Selenium-proxy-authentication) to automate that, but I don't think for watir yet.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55582859/20443541) answer might also help you for porting to watir.