# Ruby: How to store proxy authentication inside chromedriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i've created browser instance using watir like below:

```
proxies = ['--proxy-server=hostname:portnumber', '--proxy-auth=username:password']
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => proxiesle
```

but the problem above the code is cannot authenticate proxy by passing parameters `--proxy-auth=username:password`, i was wondering how could i automatically set username and proxy in chrome driver? Some solution was written in java like below:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--proxy-server=http://user:password@proxy.com:8080"));
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

how you guys to override proxy authentication inside chrome ?

Comment: is it appears as alert?

Comment: @ShubhamJain, yes it is, but it is not javascript pop up modals

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: Proxy Authentication in Watir (Chrome Driver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032288/rails-proxy-authentication-in-watir-chrome-driver)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has stopped support for URL authentication system for latest Chrome version.

I have a Java code, which will authenticate pop-up:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(username, password));
```

Convert this code in Ruby.