# how to set proxy with authentication in selenium chromedriver python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating a script that crawls one website to gather some data but the problem is that they blocked me after too many requests but using a proxy I can send more request then currently I do. I have integrated proxy with chrome option `--proxy-server`

`options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format('http://ip:port'))`

but I am using a paid proxy so it requires authentication and as below screenshot it gives the alert box for username and password

[image: selenium proxy authentication alert box]
Then I tried to use it with username and password

`options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format('http://username:password@ip:port'))`

But it also does not seems to work. I was looking for a solution and found below solution and I used it with the chrome extension [proxy auto auth](https://www.crx4chrome.com/crx/1446/) and without the chrome extension

```
proxy = {'address': settings.PROXY,
             'username': settings.PROXY_USER,
             'password': settings.PROXY_PASSWORD}

capabilities = dict(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
capabilities['proxy'] = {'proxyType': 'MANUAL',
                             'httpProxy': proxy['address'],
                             'ftpProxy': proxy['address'],
                             'sslProxy': proxy['address'],
                             'noProxy': '',
                             'class': "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
                             'autodetect': False,
                             'socksUsername': proxy['username'],
                             'socksPassword': proxy['password']}
options.add_extension(os.path.join(settings.DIR, "extension_2_0.crx")) # proxy auth extension
```

but neither of above worked properly it seems working because after above code the proxy authentication alert disappeared and when I checked my IP by googling what is my IP and confirmed that is not working.

please anyone who can help me to authenticate the proxy server on chromedriver.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

**Selenium Chrome Proxy Authentication**

*Setting chromedriver proxy with Selenium using Python*

If you need to use a proxy with python and Selenium library with chromedriver you usually use the following code (Without any username and password:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % hostname + ":" + port)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

It works fine unless proxy requires authentication. if the proxy requires you to log in with a username and password it will not work. In this case, you have to use more tricky solution that is explained below. By the way, if you whitelist your server IP address from the proxy provider or server it should not ask proxy credentials.

*HTTP Proxy Authentication with Chromedriver in Selenium*

To set up proxy authentication we will generate a special file and upload it to chromedriver dynamically using the following code below. This code configures selenium with chromedriver to use HTTP proxy that requires authentication with user/password pair.

```
import os
import zipfile

from selenium import webdriver

PROXY_HOST = '192.168.3.2'  # rotating proxy or host
PROXY_PORT = 8080 # port
PROXY_USER = 'proxy-user' # username
PROXY_PASS = 'proxy-password' # password


manifest_json = """
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
"""

background_js = """
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "%s",
            port: parseInt(%s)
        },
        bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
    };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "%s",
            password: "%s"
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
""" % (PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS)


def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        os.path.join(path, 'chromedriver'),
        chrome_options=chrome_options)
    return driver

def main():
    driver = get_chromedriver(use_proxy=True)
    #driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip+address')
    driver.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Function get_chromedriver returns configured selenium webdriver that you can use in your application. This code is tested and works just fine.

Read more about [onAuthRequired](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onAuthRequired) event in Chrome.

Comment: I apologize, but this does not work in headless mode, the error is: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://emndjklbiakacbolpojiogpiccbjieik/_generated_background_page.html
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://emndjklbiakacbolpojiogpiccbjieik/_generated_background_page.html

Comment: Extension is not supported in chrome headless mode. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372066/is-it-possible-to-run-google-chrome-in-headless-mode-with-extensions

Comment: If you're running Selenium on Mac or Linux, you can use Xvfb to run chrome in the background in a virtual display while still using extensions. Brilliant solution btw. Worked like a charm!

Comment: is there a way without creating a .zip file?

Comment: The Chromium Team recently added a 2nd headless mode: ``--headless=chrome`` which gives you the full functionality of Chrome in headless mode, and even allows extensions. (See: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c36). Also, the above solution currently uses Manifest V2 extension syntax, which will stop working in January 2023. (See: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv2-sunset/)

Comment: Extension installing does not work anymore since it is in manifest version 2. I couldn't make the sending username/password fields to work. How should we convert it to manifest v3? @itsmnthn

Comment: @hyhr I've added v3 manifest

Comment: the one caveat on white list is that my ip is in IPv6 and my proxy only supports IPV4.  So the extension is the only option.

Comment: chrome_options.add_argument("--single-process") will prevent this from working

Comment: I used this solution but modified it a bit: 1. Added the manifest.json and background.js files separately (hardcoded credentials though). 2. Placed those two files in a folder of its own. 3. used the option "--load-extension={folder_path}" to load the extension. Using zip didn't work for me in headful mode, but unzipped worked for both headless and headful mode. This version on manifest v2 is still working for me even now.

Comment: Let's say I have a magical function called make_browser() that automatically does all the heavy lifting and uses this code to connect to a proxy and creates a browser instance. But if I wanted multiple browser instances with proxies by putting the make_browser() function in a loop, do I also need to put the whole code inside of the loop too? or is just one declaration outside of the loop enough?

Comment: Does not consistently work since Chrome 114. Used to work like a charm

Answer (score 34):

Use [selenium-wire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire#proxies).

Example code from the documentation:

**HTTP proxies**

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver

options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://user:pass@192.168.10.100:8888',
        'https': 'https://user:pass@192.168.10.100:8888',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options)
```

**SOCKS proxies**

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver

options = {
   'proxy': {
        'http': 'socks5://user:pass@192.168.10.100:8888',
        'https': 'socks5://user:pass@192.168.10.100:8888',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options)
```

Install with:

```
pip install selenium-wire
```

Comment: selenium-wire does provide better usage of the proxy, but it can also hide some essential fields in the Chrome Performance Log.

Comment: using socks version with seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver is extremely slow. vs just selenium + extension ?  ideas?

Answer (score 23):

Here is a quick, creative solution that doesn't require modification of selenium's Options or uploading a file to chromedriver. It makes use of pyautogui (can use any python package that simulates key presses) to enter proxy auth details. It also uses threading to account for chrome authentication popup window that would otherwise pause the script.

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import pyautogui
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

hostname = "HOST_NAME"
port = "PORT"
proxy_username = "USERNAME"
proxy_password = "PASSWORD"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(hostname + ":" + port))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)


def enter_proxy_auth(proxy_username, proxy_password):
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.typewrite(proxy_username)
    pyautogui.press('tab')
    pyautogui.typewrite(proxy_password)
    pyautogui.press('enter')


def open_a_page(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)


Thread(target=open_a_page, args=(driver, "http://www.example.com/")).start()
Thread(target=enter_proxy_auth, args=(proxy_username, proxy_password)).start()
```

NOTE: For any serious project or test suite I would recommend opting for a more robust solution. However, if you are just experimenting and require a quick and effective solution, this is an option.

Comment: Unlike many other complicated scripts, this solution seems simple and elegant and worked like a cham. Thank you @Danny.

Comment: What would be a non-GUI solution?

Comment: Hi! been 2 years - time flies :) long story short: switched from selenium to JS-based frameworks like puppeteer and playwright for all my front-end test *specifically* to avoid consuming time issues like this. Example, in puppeteer you can do this in a few lines `puppeteerOptions: {args: ['--proxy-server=http://user:pass@ip:port']}` then `page.authenticate`... Selenium is still awesome for many applications, but for front-end tests & interacting with browser, fundamental issue is making python play nice with javascript, a cat and mouse game which I can't see changing anytime soon

Comment: I second what Ragova said - works like a charm. Thanks you!

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the same answer, but only for Java code, so here is my variant of @itsmnthn Python code.

**Don't forget to** change String fields of MainTest class to your ip, port, login, password and a chromeDriver path.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class MainTest {
    private static final String PROXY_HOST = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final String PROXY_PORT = "8080";
    private static final String PROXY_USER = "login";
    private static final String PROXY_PASS = "password";
    private static final String CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = "chromeDriverPath";
    private static final String PROXY_OPTION_TEMPLATE = "--proxy-server=http://%s";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", CHROMEDRIVER_PATH);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        String manifest_json = "{\n" +
                "  \"version\": \"1.0.0\",\n" +
                "  \"manifest_version\": 2,\n" +
                "  \"name\": \"Chrome Proxy\",\n" +
                "  \"permissions\": [\n" +
                "    \"proxy\",\n" +
                "    \"tabs\",\n" +
                "    \"unlimitedStorage\",\n" +
                "    \"storage\",\n" +
                "    \"<all_urls>\",\n" +
                "    \"webRequest\",\n" +
                "    \"webRequestBlocking\"\n" +
                "  ],\n" +
                "  \"background\": {\n" +
                "    \"scripts\": [\"background.js\"]\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"minimum_chrome_version\":\"22.0.0\"\n" +
                "}";

        String background_js = String.format("var config = {\n" +
                "  mode: \"fixed_servers\",\n" +
                "  rules: {\n" +
                "    singleProxy: {\n" +
                "      scheme: \"http\",\n" +
                "      host: \"%s\",\n" +
                "      port: parseInt(%s)\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    bypassList: [\"localhost\"]\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "};\n" +
                "\n" +
                "chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: \"regular\"}, function() {});\n" +
                "\n" +
                "function callbackFn(details) {\n" +
                "return {\n" +
                "authCredentials: {\n" +
                "username: \"%s\",\n" +
                "password: \"%s\"\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "};\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "\n" +
                "chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(\n" +
                "callbackFn,\n" +
                "{urls: [\"<all_urls>\"]},\n" +
                "['blocking']\n" +
                ");", PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("proxy_auth_plugin.zip");
        ZipOutputStream zipOS = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

        createFile("manifest.json", manifest_json);
        createFile("background.js", background_js);

        File file = new File("proxy_auth_plugin.zip");
        writeToZipFile("manifest.json", zipOS);
        writeToZipFile("background.js", zipOS);
        zipOS.close();
        fos.close();
        options.addExtensions(file);

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        try {
            driver.get("https://2ip.ru");
        } finally {
            driver.close();
        }

    }

    public static void writeToZipFile(String path, ZipOutputStream zipStream) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Writing file : '" + path + "' to zip file");
        File aFile = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(aFile);
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(path);
        zipStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
            zipStream.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
        zipStream.closeEntry();
        fis.close();
    }

    public static void createFile(String filename, String text) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(filename)) {
            out.println(text);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Still works with the latest Chrome (95); the only caveat, as it does not auto works with incognito mode - but it is a general extension problem, not this solution.

Comment: Great! The only thing that really worked for me in the end!

Answer (score 4):

Because it does not seem to be possible to directly configure the Chromedriver to use a proxy that requires authentication, you can use a local downstream proxy that does not require any authentication. This local proxy then sends all requests to your "real" proxy that you wanted to use in the first place with the required authentication.

I have used [tinyproxy](https://tinyproxy.github.io/) to do this. You can add the following line to the tinyproxy-configuration (tinyproxy.conf):

```
upstream http user:pass@host:port
```

Make sure to replace user, pass, host and port with the values of the proxy that you want to use.

Then you can configure your Chromedriver to use the tinyproxy as already described in earlier answers. Tinyprox runs on port 8888 by default, so you can reach it on 127.0.0.1:8888. As already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55582859/18421033), it is pretty easy to use a proxy without authentication:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8888')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Good idea, but tinyproxy doesn't support neither `$HTTPS_PROXY` nor HTTPS connections to it, both of which are clearly almost essential.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem - and isn´t it possible to combine the selenium-wire function with the headless function from the Options - for me this code was working for example - is there anything wrong with that?

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os, sys, time
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

path = os.path.abspath (os.path.dirname (sys.argv[0]))
cd = '/chromedriver.exe'
load_dotenv(find_dotenv()) 
PROXY_CHEAP_USER = os.environ.get("PROXY_CHEAP_USER")
PROXY_CHEAP_PW= os.environ.get("PROXY_CHEAP_PW")
PROXY_HOST = 'proxyhost.com'  # rotating proxy or host
PROXY_PORT = port # port
PROXY_USER = PROXY_CHEAP_USER # username
PROXY_PASS = PROXY_CHEAP_PW # password

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

options_seleniumWire = {
    'proxy': {
        'https': f'https://{PROXY_USER}:{PROXY_PASS}@{PROXY_HOST}:{PROXY_PORT}',
    }
}
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome (path + cd, options=options, seleniumwire_options=options_seleniumWire)
driver.get("https://ifconfig.co/")
```

I think this solution also works in headless mode.

Answer (score 3):

There is a more simple way, how you should do authentication to proxy with selenium! I don't know from which version it works, but in selenium-api-4.5.3 for java there is a interface `HasAuthentication`. You can use `register` method after initializing driver to set user+password for whole browser.

This worked for me with chromium:

```
((ChromiumDriver) driver).register(() -> new UsernameAndPassword("USER", "PASS"));
```

and set Proxy in options

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability("proxy", initProxy());
new ChromeDriver(options);
```

works for me in headless mode too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is manifest version 3 to accompany latest versions of Chrome and @itsmnthn solution

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestAuthProvider"
        ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
```

And C# class that handles this issue (again, based on @itsmnthn solution)

```
public class ProxiedChromeClient : IDisposable
{
    private const string MANIFEST_JSON = @"
    {
        ""version"": ""1.0.0"",
        ""manifest_version"": 3,
        ""name"": ""Chrome Proxy"",
        ""permissions"": [
            ""proxy"",
            ""tabs"",
            ""unlimitedStorage"",
            ""storage"",
            ""webRequest"",
            ""webRequestAuthProvider""
            ],
        ""host_permissions"": [
            ""<all_urls>""
        ],
        ""background"": {
            ""service_worker"": ""background.js""
        },
        ""minimum_chrome_version"":""22.0.0""
    }";

    private const string BACKGROUND_JS = @"
    var config = {{
        mode: ""fixed_servers"",
        rules: {{
            singleProxy: {{
                scheme: ""{0}"",
                host: ""{1}"",
                port: parseInt({2})
            }},
            bypassList: [""localhost""]
        }}
    }};

    chrome.proxy.settings.set({{value: config, scope: ""regular""}}, function() {{}});

    function callbackFn(details) {{
        return {{
            authCredentials: {{
                username: ""{3}"",
                password: ""{4}""
            }}
        }};
    }}

    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
        callbackFn,
        {{urls: [""<all_urls>""]}},
        ['blocking']
    );";

    protected ProxiedChromeClient(ProxyInfo proxy = null)
    {
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        if (proxy != null)
        {
            extensionPath = CreateProxyExtension(proxy);
            options.AddExtension(extensionPath);
        }

        chromeDriverInstance = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }


    protected readonly ChromeDriver chromeDriverInstance;
    private readonly object @lock = new();
    private readonly string extensionPath;

    private static string CreateProxyExtension(ProxyInfo proxy)
    {
        // per https://stackoverflow.com/a/55582859/307584
        var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        using var z = new ZipArchive(new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Create), ZipArchiveMode.Create);
        var entry = z.CreateEntry("manifest.json");
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
        {
            writer.Write(MANIFEST_JSON);
        }

        entry = z.CreateEntry("background.js");
        var url = new Uri(proxy.Url);
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
        {
            writer.Write(BACKGROUND_JS, url.Scheme, url.Host, url.Port, proxy.User, proxy.Password);
        }

        return tempFile;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (@lock)
        {
            chromeDriverInstance.Quit();
            if (extensionPath != null)
            {
                File.Delete(extensionPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andry. Thank you for the conversion. I am getting error while trying to install it manually. It gives the following errors: "Permission 'webRequestAuthProvider' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed." and "Unchecked runtime.lastError: You do not have permission to use blocking webRequest listeners. Be sure to declare the webRequestBlocking permission in your manifest."

Comment: In the migration page, it is suggested to use declarativeNetRequest for v3.

Answer (score 1):

Along the way,  in the updates the solution using the extension doesnt work (windows at least), while mac and linux does.
I think it was chromedriver v2.44 the last working version with extensions

Comment: **update** New version of ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40 **do** work again with addon proxy.

Answer (score 1):

We have created a [public open source solution](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-authenticated-proxy/) for solving that exact case, by combining these awesome answers in this thread and some other answers about how to properly include it in Chrome. Starting with version 114 there have been some significant manifest.json changes. The pypi package abstracts away all the difficulty of having authenticated proxies in selenium. We plan to support it as we heavily rely on it for an enterprise application.

Just run

```
pip install selenium-authenticated-proxy
```

This is how you can set it up with your webdriver:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_authenticated_proxy import SeleniumAuthenticatedProxy

# Initialize Chrome options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# Initialize SeleniumAuthenticatedProxy
proxy_helper = SeleniumAuthenticatedProxy(proxy_url="http://username:password@proxy-server.com")

# Enrich Chrome options with proxy authentication
proxy_helper.enrich_chrome_options(chrome_options)

# Start WebDriver with enriched options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

# Your automation or scraping code here
```

You can specify a custom folder for temporary storage of generated Chrome extensions.

```py
proxy_helper = SeleniumAuthenticatedProxy(proxy_url="http://username:password@proxy-server.com", tmp_folder="/path/to/tmp/folder")
```

Comment: works! Have been using selewire for years, but now ran into some SSE related issues. First solution is rather complex.

Answer (score 0):

There are *several workarounds* for this issue, but it is currently impossible to resolve the authentication dialogue box in Selenium. See [this issue](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/385):

> There is currently no way to handle HTTP authentication prompts when navigating to a page, only pre-authentication with username/password in the URL works (and, apparently, not without workarounds in some browsers like IE).