# How to set proxy with auth credentials in selenium chromedriver 77.0.8.3865.40 python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have used the extension plugin to set proxy with authentication in selenium python. It worked before, but it's not working anymore with the latest chromedriver version 77.0.3865.40.

PS: The solution that I said worked before is from the answer of Its_mnthn from this question: [how to set proxy with authentication in selenium chromedriver python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582136/how-to-set-proxy-with-authentication-in-selenium-chromedriver-python)

Can anybody helped me please? It is important that I have to use chromedriver for this.

Thank you :)

Comment: Saw this on selenium GH. Hope i can help https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3025#issuecomment-256846250

Comment: version of ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40 do work again with addon proxy. that is a comment in that answer

Comment: Not an answer, but just wondering: what is your reasoning for sticking to this newer version instead of just going for the older one?