# How to connect through private proxy selenium

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, webdriver

How to connect through private proxy (user:pass@ip:port) using selenium web driver? When I try to connect it shows me

`ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES`

I googled a lot, but everywhere the information is only about common proxies (ip:port). If anyone knows or has come across this - tell me, please. Thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://google.com'
proxy = '' # user:pass@ip:port
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server=http://{proxy}')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser.get(url)
```

Comment: just curious, but have tried setting the OS to use the proxy?  You should be able to set the proxytype to "system" in webdriver (if they've implemented it): https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#proxy

Comment: After some more searching, I found a solution thanks to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55582859/11924354