# No internet connection while using selenium proxy

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I am a newbie in using selenium. When I use proxy chrome shows there is no internet connection. I have checked my internet connection and looked for possible solutions on the internet but failed. I also restarted my computer but it did not work.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from time import sleep

    PROXY = '43.225.164.59:38829'


    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options,         
                              executable_path='C:\webscraping\chromedriver')
    driver.get('https://whatismyipaddress.com/')

    sleep(6)

    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is looking good, **it should works**.

Do you use proxy with **authentification**? If do, you should use another way to enable proxy - [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55582859/18990090) (Selenium doesn't support authentification of proxy).

You should also be sure, that **proxy is working**. Check it with curl:

If you're using **public** proxy:

```bash
curl https://2ip.ru/ -x "http://proxy_host:proxy_port"
```

If you're using **private** proxy with authentification:

```bash
curl https://2ip.ru/ -x "http://proxy_user:proxy_pwd@proxy_host:proxy_port"
```

Both of these commands will return **your ip address** (it should be equal to **proxy address** you use.