# Proxy authentication selenium ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I attempted to follow this post [here][1]:
[how to set proxy with authentication in selenium chromedriver python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582136/how-to-set-proxy-with-authentication-in-selenium-chromedriver-python) to use an authenticated proxy with Chome Webdriver. It doesn't work and I get ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED from Chrome. Is there a new solution to this or does the code from the linked StackOverflow need to be updated? I am using ChromeDriver v81 for Windows.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? Faving the same problem with ChromeDriver V85 and Java-Selenium

Comment: I never ended up resolving it unfortunately.