# Python Selenium - Proxy with authentication on headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I need to run proxies that requires authentication on selenium in headless mode.

I think many people are aware of the answer given on this post and it does work very well honestly *But only In NON Headless Mode. As extensions are no longer supported in headless mode* [how to set proxy with authentication in selenium chromedriver python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582136/how-to-set-proxy-with-authentication-in-selenium-chromedriver-python)

Besides that method, another very good method to run proxies that works in headless mode is by using the module `selenium-wire`. However, selenium-wire can only run in `HTTP`. To run `HTTPS` you would need to import a generated certificate into google chrome. So you cant run `HTTPS` programmatically.

Is there any good options to run proxies with authentication in headless mode? I'm sure many of us are wondering the same thing.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @LukeHamilton Sadly no :( It seems like Selenium just doesn't support that. So for my project, I changed to using Puppeteer with Node.JS instead as that supported way more features than selenium :)