# using selenium(python) to open multiple windows while each window have a unique authenticated proxy(payed proxy)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, proxy

am creating a script that opens multiple windows while every window use a unique authenticated proxy, I managed to do that but with free proxies but am having troubles while having a paid ones
I used this solution to authenticate my proxies ([how to set proxy with authentication in selenium chromedriver python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582136/how-to-set-proxy-with-authentication-in-selenium-chromedriver-python))but couldn't find a way to use this solution to adapt it with my code.

```
import os
import zipfile
import time
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY_HOST = 'host'  # rotating proxy
PROXY_PORT = 'port'
PROXY_USER = 'user'
PROXY_PASS = 'pass'


manifest_json = """
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
"""

background_js = """
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
          singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "%s",
            port: parseInt(%s)
          },
          bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
      };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "%s",
            password: "%s"
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
""" % (PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS)


def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('yourpath',options=chrome_options)
    return driver

def main():
    driver = get_chromedriver(use_proxy=True)
    #driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip+address')
    driver.get('https://whatismyipaddress.com/')


main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using selenium wire

```
    from seleniumwire import webdriver
    proxy_host = ['host', 'host', 'host', 'host']  # rotating proxy
proxy_port = ['port', 'port', 'port', 'port']
proxy_username = ['username', 'username', 'username', 'username']
proxy_password = ['password', 'password', 'password', 'password']
    def new(username,password,host,port):
         options = {
             'proxy': {
                'http': 'http://%s:%s@%s:%s'%(username,password,host,port),
                 'https': 'http://%s:%s@%s:%s'%(username,password,host,port),
                 'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1' # excludes
         }
     }
         return options
    for username, password, host, port in zip(proxy_username, proxy_password, proxy_host, proxy_port):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="your path",seleniumwire_options=new(username, password, host, port))
        driver.get('https://whatismyipaddress.com/')
```