# Selenium proxy with authentication

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to use selenium and proxy with authentication.
I have a few constraints

1. I can't use selenium-wire  (only pure selenium allowed)
2. I have to use headless mode (e.g. `chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")`)

I read this answer [Python proxy authentication through Selenium chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64829313/python-proxy-authentication-through-selenium-chromedriver/64838654#64838654) but it doesn't work for headless mode.

**Is it possible to use proxy with authentication in my case?** (browser(Chrome, Firefox) is not important)

---

**I need python function to create selenium webdriver object authenticate to proxy**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set proxy with authentication in selenium chromedriver python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582136/how-to-set-proxy-with-authentication-in-selenium-chromedriver-python). Answer link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55582859/5372079

Comment: No, because 
this does not work in headless mode,  see comments!!!

Comment: yes, my bad because headless mode doesn't support extension. Can you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/56276796/5372079

Comment: I can't use seleniumwire, only pure selenium is avaliable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't because you need a GUI to handle it with selenium in your case
so I would recommend using a virtual display like Xvfb display server

You can use PyVirtualDisplay (a Python wrapper for Xvfb) to run headless.

for Linux

```
sudo apt-get install firefox xvfb
```

install virtual display for python

```
pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

then

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# now Firefox will run in a virtual display. 
# you will not see the browser.
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

in this case, you do not need to add `options.add_argument("--headless")` argument and you can follow the answers commented above as a solution or doing it your way but I think this is the best solution for using pure selenium for proxy

Comment: Why do i need GUI to handle work with proxy? (for example i can use proxy without authentication in HEADLESS mode)

Comment: because there is an alert/prompt that you should interact with...

Comment: the easiest way is virtual display but there is another solution which is [mitmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy) which is way harder and complicated that's why I recommended `Xvfb`

Comment: in the `mitmproxy` case, you have to run a separate proxy without authentication and redirect it to the target proxy with authentication, as I said the `Xvfb` is easier and more logical, by the way, headless selenium itself does not support authentication, See [Issue 718235](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718235) and [Issue 706008](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c5)