# Supplement for adding proxy information in Selenium

Tags: python, proxy

I found a very good question about adding proxy username and password information. I tried it and it worked 100% perfectly (thanks a lot)

Except for one pretty minor problem. That is, when the parameter use_proxy = False is set (mean no proxy is used), when running, it still requires entering previously saved proxy information, but not automatically using the default IP.

I want to ask is there any way to fix this error? For example, if use_proxy = True, use the provided proxy information. If use_proxy = False, it will automatically skip and use the computer's default IP to connect to the network.

Content links: [how to set proxy with authentication in selenium chromedriver python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582136/how-to-set-proxy-with-authentication-in-selenium-chromedriver-python)