# Python/selenium how to use proxy with undetected-chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

whenever I try to use a proxy with undetedted-chromedriver, it just doesn't work and diplays my ip.
When I use the normal webdriver, it works perfectly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep


ip_port = "ip:port"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % ip_port)
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.myexternalip.com/raw')
sleep(999)
```

How can I make the proxy work with undetected chromedriver?

This is the site https://www.myexternalip.com/raw :
With undetected chromedriver (gives my actual ip)

[image: ip adress]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check out the answer from the other thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582136/how-to-set-proxy-with-authentication-in-selenium-chromedriver-python#answer-55582859)

Comment: @NaphatTheerawat its not about authentication, its about making the proxy work with undetected-chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

Got it work with:

```py
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=ip:port')
driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.myexternalip.com/raw')
```

Comment: It's the same as in question

Answer (score 0):

I assume you set up a green flag for your machine on your server, so you don't need to enter the login and password for the server:

```
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=185.195.81.152:12573') 
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://185.195.81.152:12573') # socks5
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=https://185.195.81.152:12573') # https
```

also suggest using:

```
options.add_argument('--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>')
```

If you didn't green flag your machines IP to the server, then you'll need to provide the login and password as well:

```
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=proxy_username:proxy_password@proxy_ip:proxy_port')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a chrome extension to change your IP using a proxy.
For example I use [SwitchyOmega](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif). Then I set the proxy inside the extension and it works completely fine.