# How undetected-chromedriver change proxy?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

How undetected-chromedriver change proxy?
I need use it to crawl some webpages, and I want to make it one page, one proxy. any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python/selenium how to use proxy with undetected-chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71728498/python-selenium-how-to-use-proxy-with-undetected-chromedriver)