# Selenium proxy authentication for multiple parallel drivers

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, undetected-chromedriver

I am making a bot that can auto checkout,
I want that every driver will authenticate and use a proxy.
the following code is how I run multiple drivers in parallel using threads:

```
for i in range(0, buynumber):
   option.append(Options())
   option[i].add_argument("--disable-gpu")
   option[i].add_argument("--incognito")
for i in range(0, buynumber):
    driver.insert(i, uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=option[i]))
for i in threads:
    i.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

If possible, I also want the drivers to run headless, and without using seleniumwire because it makes the drivers run a whole lot slower.

also, I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55582859/19758453) answer, but didn't manage to implement it into my code (I am a beginner). It will also help if this code can be implemented.