# Selenium python remove extension

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I used code for proxy from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55582859/16240388) and than I cant disable the proxy extension or remove it. I tried to find it on extensions folder in profile folder but there is no extensions installed via add.extension

The code works well and I thought I can just type use_proxy=False and the extension would not try to connect again but it tries to connect always even I launch browser without python selenium

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to remove this extension so I can launch chrome profile as usual without any code, by hands, and the browser will not try to connect to the proxy

Comment: if it would helps
Only profiles I used with the proxy code not working now(trying to connect to proxy). Other profiles works as usual

Answer (score 0):

With the Python statement from the referenced question [how to set proxy with authentication in selenium chromedriver python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582136/how-to-set-proxy-with-authentication-in-selenium-chromedriver-python/55582859#55582859)

```py
options.add_extension(os.path.join(settings.DIR, "extension_2_0.crx")) # proxy auth extension
```

you probably installed the Chrome extension "Proxy Auto Auth":

- [Proxy Auto Auth - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-auto-auth/ggmdpepbjljkkkdaklfihhngmmgmpggp)
- original link from the question: [Proxy Auto Auth](https://www.crx4chrome.com/crx/1446/)

If this extension is active it also works when using Chrome alone. It does not need your Python script, it was just added to Chrome this way.

You can uninstall or remove the extension from Chrome, see [Uninstall an extensions - Chrome Web Store Help](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769#uninstall-extension).