# I have a problem with setting credentials of an authenticated proxy in my code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I tried lots of things.

1. Sending host, port, username, and password as a whole string to chrome options. Does not work.
2. Devtools do not work for me, because the file 'devtools' is not seen. But it is not the case.
3. I decided to make an extension for Chrome. I read articles/posts on Stack Overflow, but it does not seem to work either. **My goal is to set credentials of proxy to run Selenium in headless mode**.

   I used mostly this post [how to set proxy with authentication in selenium chromedriver python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582136/how-to-set-proxy-with-authentication-in-selenium-chromedriver-python/71413054#71413054) as a reference and this article: https://codenineeight.medium.com/proxy-with-authentication-for-chrome-manifest-v3-using-python-e5efeb0f11a.

   Firstly, I tested in Chrome Browser. Since I got the error '*connection is not private'*, I decided to run my code

   (I figured out that I need

   ```
   options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
   ```

   ).

   The proxy is not set anyway, which is interesting as I did everything as other people did, I suppose.

   If you have an idea, help me, please. I am stuck  :(

This is the app/services/tiktok/*selenium_driver.rb*, where I create a chrome webdriver:

```
require 'singleton'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'webdrivers/chromedriver'

class ChromeDriver
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    Webdrivers::Chromedriver.required_version = '114.0.5735.90'

    @driver = create_driver
  end

  def create_driver

    # I commented it out in order for you to check if proxy (non-authenticated) is being set correctly.
    #
    # proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(
    #   http: "#{ENV['PROXY_HOST']}:#{ENV['PROXY_PORT']}",
    #   ssl: "#{ENV['PROXY_HOST']}:#{ENV['PROXY_PORT']}",
    #   ftp: "#{ENV['PROXY_HOST']}:#{ENV['PROXY_PORT']}"
    # )

    # capabilities are required to set non-authenticated proxy.
    #
    # cap = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(proxy: proxy)

    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument('--incognito')
    # options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

    prefs = {
      'profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications' => 1,
      'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads' => 1,
      'profile.default_content_setting_values.muted' => true
    }

    prefs.each do |name, value|
      options.add_preference(name, value)
    end


    # Authenticated proxy for Chrome is set in the extension.
    # This needs to be done to set proxy's credentials and use --headless mode.
    # But it does not work for some reason.
    # If you use .zip, WebDriver won't find the extension. It needs to be .crx
    #
    # Please, do not change the path. This works only with absolute path.
    path_to_extension = 'app/services/tiktok/manifest.crx'
    options.add_extension(path_to_extension)

    # Add capabilities: cap after options if you want to use an ordinary proxy.
    #
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
    driver
  end

  def sleep_time(seconds)
    sleep(seconds)
  end

  def scroll_to_bottom
    @driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
    sleep_time(2)
  end

  def navigate_to(url)
    @driver.navigate.to(url)
  end

  def quit
    @driver.quit
  end

  def find_elements(elements)
    @driver.find_elements(elements)
  end

  def page_source
    @driver.page_source
  end
end
```

The *app/services/tiktok/manifest/background.js* file:

```
require('dotenv').config();

let config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: "https",
            host: process.env.PROXY_HOST,
            port: process.env.PROXY_PORT
        }
    }
};

chrome.proxy.settings.set({ value: config, scope: "regular" }, function () {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: process.env.PROXY_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.PROXY_PASSWORD
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    callbackFn,
    { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
    ['blocking']
);
```

**This is not the problem with environmental variables as you might think. I passed necessary values, still nothing.**

This is *app/services/tiktok/manifest/manifest.json* file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Chrome Proxy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "proxy",
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestAuthProvider",
    "declarativeNetRequest"
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

I also have *app/services/tiktok/manifest.crx* file. The zip format didn't work for me and I had *WebDriver didn't find the extension* error. **It needs to be .crx.**

**Crx file is made with 'Pack Extension' option in Chrome.**

**When I run the program, i get two errors in the browser console**:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
secsdk-lastest.umd.js:5 
Error: Failed to fetch csrf token: host=www.tiktok.com status=404 statusText=
    at c.<anonymous>
```

But I don't understand if this is the case.

Thank you all for your time.