I can't connect to a proxy using Selenium in Python
First of all, I'm sure the proxy is definitely working. I can use it when I try it from Windows's own proxy settings, but I can't connect to the proxy with Selenium.
(Chrome, driver, and Selenium are up to date)
Here’s my code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

# Proxy ayarları
proxy_host = ""
proxy_port = ""
proxy_user = ""
proxy_pass = ""
proxy_url = f"http://{proxy_user}:{proxy_pass}@{proxy_host}:{proxy_port}"

# Chrome seçeneklerini ayarlama
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy_url}')

# ChromeDriver'ı başlatma
chrome_driver_path = "driver/chromedriver.exe"
service = Service(chrome_driver_path)

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    print("Page Source:", driver.page_source)
except WebDriverException as e:
    print("WebDriverException:", e)
finally:
    driver.quit()

I asked AI and opened a topic in the forums, but I couldn't find a solution. My goal is to connect to a Webdriver using a proxy.

Cant use proxy with authentication, well you can with selenium-wire or your custom proxy server that makes the authentication and you request proxy to your server, im pretty sure is dupe question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582136/how-to-set-proxy-with-authentication-in-selenium-chromedriver-python  check library "selenium-authenticated-proxy/" https://pypi.org/project/selenium-authenticated-proxy/ they made a solution
